# $L^p$ not sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I am trying to show that for $1\leq p<\infty$ the Lebesgue-space $L^p[0,1]$ is not sequentially compact, i.e. there exists a bounded sequence with no convergent subsequence.

I have done similar proofs for spaces of continouus functions, but I cannot think of an example of such a sequence in say $L^2[0,1]$. Can anyone help me out with an example of such a sequence? Thanks!

Comment: Can you find infinitely many functions in $L^2([0,1])$ that have norm 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about $\sqrt{\sin{n\pi x}}$, this converges in $L^2$, since:

$\int_0^1|\sqrt{\sin(n\pi x)}|^2 dx=\int_0^1\sin(n\pi x)dx=\frac{2}{n\pi}\to 0$

But $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\sin{n\pi x}}$ is not a function.

Comment: This is a good example! Thanks!

Comment: No worries, I think it would hold in all $L^p$ spaces by taking the $p$-th root.

Comment: Didn't you just show there that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{sin(n\pi x)}= 0$ in the $L^{2}$ topology? Every subsequence of this sequence converges in $L^{2}$, so how is this a counter example?

Comment: I have shown that the sequence is bounded in $L^2$ but the limit itself is not a function and so is not in $L^2$.